# Php reference function not found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently working in showing charts using php, html. I have been using a library fusionCharts.php which has been proved working before. However, right now, I have been getting error from the following line >

```
<?php

class FusionCharts {

    private $constructorOptions = [];
    private $constructorTemplate = <<<EOD
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            new FusionCharts(__constructorOptions__);
        });
    </script>
EOD;
    private $renderTemplate = <<<EOD
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            FusionCharts("__chartId__").render();
        });
    </script>
EOD;
```

But firebug shows that my error is being shown from another php funcion, graph.php. I have getting the error from the line 16 which is the   line.

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<!-- You need to include the following JS file to render the chart.
When you make your own charts, make sure that the path to this JS file is correct.
Else, you will get JavaScript errors. -->

<script src="js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
```

And the error being thrown:

```
 ReferenceError: FusionCharts is not defined
 FusionCharts.ready(function () {  graph.php (line 16, col 12)
 ReferenceError: FusionCharts is not defined
 FusionCharts.ready(function () {
```

I am adding all the files below:

fusioncharts.js

```
function fusioncharts_clickbar(){
  var chartargs = '';
  var chartid = arguments[0];
  for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
     chartargs = chartargs + arguments[i] + '/';
  }
  $.get(Drupal.settings.basePath +"/fusioncharts/data/"+ chartargs ,
    function(data){
       updateChartXML(chartid, data);
  }
); 
}
```

fusioncharts.php

```
<?php

class FusionCharts {

    private $constructorOptions = [];
    private $constructorTemplate = <<<EOD
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            new FusionCharts(__constructorOptions__);
        });
    </script>
    EOD;
    private $renderTemplate = <<<EOD
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            FusionCharts("__chartId__").render();
        });
    </script>
    EOD;

    // constructor
    function __construct($type, $id, $width = 400, $height = 300, $renderAt, $dataFormat, $dataSource) {
        isset($type) ? $this->constructorOptions['type'] = $type : '';
        isset($id) ? $this->constructorOptions['id'] = $id : 'php-fc-'.time();
        isset($width) ? $this->constructorOptions['width'] = $width : '';
        isset($height) ? $this->constructorOptions['height'] = $height : '';
        isset($renderAt) ? $this->constructorOptions['renderAt'] = $renderAt : '';
        isset($dataFormat) ? $this->constructorOptions['dataFormat'] = $dataFormat : '';
        isset($dataSource) ? $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'] = $dataSource : '';

        $tempArray = [];
        foreach($this->constructorOptions as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === 'dataSource') {
                $tempArray['dataSource'] = '__dataSource__';
            } else {
                $tempArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        $jsonEncodedOptions = json_encode($tempArray);

        if ($dataFormat === 'json') {
            $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/\"__dataSource__\"/', $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'], $jsonEncodedOptions);
        } elseif ($dataFormat === 'xml') { 
            $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/\"__dataSource__\"/', '\'__dataSource__\'', $jsonEncodedOptions);
            $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/__dataSource__/', $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'], $jsonEncodedOptions);
        } elseif ($dataFormat === 'xmlurl') {
            $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/__dataSource__/', $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'], $jsonEncodedOptions);
        } elseif ($dataFormat === 'jsonurl') {
            $jsonEncodedOptions = preg_replace('/__dataSource__/', $this->constructorOptions['dataSource'], $jsonEncodedOptions);
        }
        $newChartHTML = preg_replace('/__constructorOptions__/', $jsonEncodedOptions, $this->constructorTemplate);

        echo $newChartHTML;

    }

    // render the chart created
    // It prints a script and calls the FusionCharts javascript render method of created chart
    function render() {
       $renderHTML = preg_replace('/__chartId__/', $this->constructorOptions['id'], $this->renderTemplate);
       echo $renderHTML;

    }

}
?>
```

graph.php

```
   <?php
   require ("fusioncharts.php");
   error_reporting(E_ERROR);

   header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
   mysql_select_db("oligolilatest",$con);
   ?>
   <html>
   <head>
  <title>Comparison of data with other</title>
    <p> fdsfdsfds fsd f dsf sdf ds f</p>
  <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

   <!-- You need to include the following JS file to render the chart.
When you make your own charts, make sure that the path to this JS file is correct.
    Else, you will get JavaScript errors. -->

    <script src="js/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php

    $query = "SELECT UserID,FirstName FROM customerregistration ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    //echo "here1";
    // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
    if ($result) {
        // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
          // echo "here11";
        $arrData = array(
            "chart" => array(
              "caption" => "Number of User and Customer in the website",
              "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
              "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
              "borderAlpha"=> "20",
              "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
              "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
              "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
              "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
              "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
              "showValues" => "0",
              "divlineColor" => "#999999",
              "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
              "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0"
            )
        );

        $arrData["data"] = array();


// Push the data into the array
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($arrData["data"], array(
            "label" => $row["FirstName"],
            "value" => $row["UserID"],

            )
        );
        }

        /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */
          // echo "here3";
        $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);
        echo $jsonEncodedData;

     /*Create an object for the column chart using the FusionCharts PHP class constructor. Syntax for the constructor is ` FusionCharts("type of chart", "unique chart id", width of the chart, height of the chart, "div id to render the chart", "data format", "data source")`. Because we are using JSON data to render the chart, the data format will be `json`. The variable `$jsonEncodeData` holds all the JSON data for the chart, and will be passed as the value for the data source parameter of the constructor.*/

        $columnChart = new FusionCharts("column2D", "myFirstChart" , 600, 300, "chart-1", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

        // Render the chart
        $columnChart->render();

     }

     ?>
     <div id="chart-1"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here-->
     </div> </body></html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is you're trying to execute `FusionCharts.ready(function () {` before `<script src="js/fusioncharts.js"></script>` has loaded

Comment: I tried this but did not work.

Comment: you tried what exactly?

Comment: I added script tag before render function so how could FusionCharts.ready(function ()  can execute before script....I am stuck in this point can't get any chart.Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have given us quite some code to plow through; and it seems the `fusioncharts.js` you include in your `<HEAD>` (which you have also included in your post) simply doesn't include the FusionCharts class so there must be additional javascript files you need to include. Looking at their documentation you also need to include the library like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js"></script>
```

Don't you include this library already in your other, working pages?

Comment: I have added all the other libraries as well. However, the error still exist.

Current error : ReferenceError: FusionCharts is not defined
Same as before..

Comment: Show us a list of all javascripts that you include on your page. Which one contains the string `window.FusionCharts.version`?

Comment: I added below script file:
script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts/FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts/FusionCharts.HC.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="FusionCharts/jquery.min.js"></script>
but did not find window.FusionCharts.version in any script file